# How to install CryptoNote-Lite pool mining software on macOS?

Tags: cpu-mining, aeon, macos, mining-software

I want to pool mine Aeon with a CPU on macOS. How do install a CryptoNote-Lite miner? Preferably using open-source where I can compile myself (procedure needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Jaste's [comment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Aeon/comments/75orv6/aeonstakcpu_on_mac_os/do8g709/), I tried compiling **AEON-STAK-CPU** on macOS Sierra (10.12.6). I encountered a few issues, this is how it worked for me:

## Installation

1. Make sure Apple's Xcode and [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) are installed.
2. Download the source code from shyba's [AEON-STAK-CPU GitHub repository](https://github.com/shyba/aeon-stak-cpu). Click the green button <kbd>Clone or download</kbd> and then <kbd>Download ZIP</kbd>. Unzip it.
3. Install a few dependencies using Homebrew (I already had the last 2 apparently):

   - `brew install libmicrohttpd`
   - `brew install cmake`
   - `brew install openssl`
4. `cmake . -DMICROHTTPD_ENABLE=OFF -DHWLOC_ENABLE=OFF`
5. `make`

This produced the binary `aeon-stak-cpu` in the `bin` subdirectory.

## Note

I would have prefered to not disable those 2 options during the `cmake` step. Even though I had installed `libmicrohttpd` using Homebrew, I couldn't find a way to get it to work yet. If anyone knows how to specify it, please say so.

## Configuration

Using the miner requires you to configure the `config.txt` file first. Besides, the typical pool and your wallet information, which every mining pool's "Getting Started" page normally shows, you'll also have to update the `cpu_threads_conf` section in it. Fortunately, it will be shown when you first start it, so just copy and paste it.

## Troubleshooting

In addition to that, I also get the following error:

`MEMORY ALLOC FAILED: mmap failed`

I resolved it by following the advice in [GitHub issue #8](https://github.com/shyba/aeon-stak-cpu/issues/8) and changing the following part in the `config.txt` file: `"use_slow_memory" : "always",` instead of `"use_slow_memory" : "never",`.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's been a while since you asked this, but in case anyone else is wondering, you can easily install [xmrig](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig) on MacOS by following the build instructions on Github.

First you need to install Xcode from the App Store, and then you have to install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

Once you have those dependencies, you need to run the commands given on the xmrig [OS X Build instructions](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/wiki/OS-X-Build) page (from a Terminal window):

```
brew install cmake libuv
git clone https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig.git
cd xmrig
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

Once the compile process finishes successfully, there will be a binary executable in the build directory named `xmrig`.  You can verify that it is there by running this command in the build directory:

```
ls -lah | grep xmrig
```

Run xmrig in OS X the same way you would in Linux.  From the build directory, run the following command (I've included my preferred pool... feel free to replace it with whatever you use):

```
./xmrig -a cryptonight-lite -o "mine.aeon-pool.com:3333" - u YOUR_WALLET_ADDRESS -p x
```

You can optionally specify a donation level. By default, xmrig donates 5% of your mining time to the developer, but you can set it as low as 1%, depending on your generosity preferences.

Note: If you have a good CPU (hashrates over 300 H/s), you might want to mine on port `5555` instead of `3333`, since it will start you at a higher difficulty (better earnings). Check your pool's "Getting Started" page for more details about what port numbers and difficulties are available.

Comment: could you please write the command that has to be used as xmrig.exe would be for windows what is for mac ...

Comment: @TaraqKamdar I added that for you. Sorry. I've been a Linux sysadmin for 10 years, so I sometimes forget that other people don't know how to run programs from a Unix terminal.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot get this to work. Initial error I had was `Could NOT find UV (missing: UV_LIBRARY UV_INCLUDE_DIR)`, which was solved by doing `cmake .. -DUV_INCLUDE_DIR=… -DUV_LIBRARY=…` per [GitHub issue 72](https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/issues/72). However, then needed to add `-DWITH_HTTPD=OFF`. And after that, I am stuck with another error `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files: MHD_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)` which I have no idea how to resolve.

Comment: @dpzz You should not be getting errors about cmake being unable to find UV if you properly installed UV using `brew install libuv`. Also, what version of OS X are you using? My successful compile was in Sierra. I haven't updated to High Sierra.

Comment: @blendenzo I installed UV like you quoted (together with cmake as in the instructions above). Those UV errors were fixed with the 2 `-D` flags as I commented. However, the `MHD_LIBRARY` error I could not solve. I am also on Sierra (10.12.6). Strange …